# ApplicationInsight does not exist in the namespace Microsoft

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal

I've been working my way through video training series on Microsoft's Virtual Academy. The series I'm watching is titled "Windows 10 Development for Absolute Beginners" I'm at the penultimate video when I ran into a problem. Bob Tabor put the following into the constructor of the App class (in App.xaml.cs):

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Metadata |
    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Session);
```

However, this line doesn't work at all for me. I'm getting red squiggly lines under Microsoft.ApplicationInsights. And when I compile I get the following error message:

> The type or namespace name 'ApplicationInsights' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have tried to add a reference to that, but it didn't work. In fact VS 2017 told me outright that it was impossible to add the reference I'd found.

I'm thinking that the problem is because I'm using VS 2017, whereas when Bob Tabor did the videos he was using VS 2015. Something has changed in the configuration, but I don't understand what. I'm sure the issue is that I need to include some sort of NuGet package. I'd be delighted to do so, only I've no idea what NuGet package to install.

I'm developing for Windows 10, using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

Comment: If you right click your project in solution explorer, it looks like there should be an option to add application Insights sdk into your project. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

For the ["Windows 10 Development for Absolute Beginners"](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners?page=7) series videos,there is a correspondent sample [here](https://github.com/Windows-Readiness/AbsoluteBeginnersWin10). If you opened [one project](https://github.com/Windows-Readiness/AbsoluteBeginnersWin10/tree/master/UWP-079/UWP-079/CortanaExample) you are referenced and build, you will find there are three `ApplicationInsights` relative Nuget packages referenced, and one `ApplicationInsights.config` file in the project. This should caused by when OS build is 10240, you create a new Windows 10 universal application in Visual Studio that a reference to `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` is added to the references folder automatically. And after that, new builds coming without adding this package automatically.

So that if you just need the error gone you may add the same three Nuget packages:[`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 1.0.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/1.0.0),[`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps 1.0.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps/1.0.0),[`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel 1.0.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel/1.0.0) manually.

But actually, [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/2.4.0) is **not supported UWP app starting 2.0.0**. Currently you should not use [`ApplicationInsights`](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home) for UWP app which may be deprecated, but use [HockeyApp SDK](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sunteen. I wasn't aware of that GitHub repo!